# Value in only allowing access to backend from specifc IPs

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, deny, restriction

I have a Load Balancer in front of several nginx web servers. I want to lock down my web servers as much as possible so I've added this to the `http` block in my `nginx.conf`:

```
allow {internal_ip_of_load_balancer};
deny all;
```

As I understand it, this will only allow requests from my Load Balancer to hit nginx. Is there much of a benefit from doing this?

Comment: Are the web servers publicly reachable?

Comment: Yes, @gf_. They are publicly reachable websites.

Comment: Are you doing anything specific regarding the traffic at the load balancer?

Comment: some IP range blocking based on country.

Comment: If your load balancer is only for given ports it works as a firewall, preventing direct access reduces vulnerability to some threats.